# Bruteforcing a windows mapped network drive with half of the digits known

Tags: windows, kali-linux, hydra

How do you bruteforce a windows mapped network drive on lan? I know half of the password already and have created a wordlist with crunch. I am not sure how to bruteforce it using hydra or any other script available on kali linux. My question is how do i direct hydra to the mapped drive, for ex //192.168.2.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attack the SMB protocol with your brute username / password lists.

- Hydra has the [smb switch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvrHHyymyNE) can be used
- nmap has a [smb-brute](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-brute.html) script which can be used

Remember that if you're attacking a network user you'll want to account for the domain in the username, and bear in mind that dictionary attacks are very noisy.